# How to use shorthand es6 imports in node 10+

Tags: node.js

In node v9.1.0 the following code works when utilizing with the `experimental-modules` flag:

`import foo from './utilities/foo'`

This fails in node v10.16.3. Instead I have to do the following:

`import foo from './utilities/foo.mjs`

Is there a way to get the older behavior back?

Comment: The docs explicitly state that [the file extension is mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions), but it may be possible to implement a [resolve hook](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolve_hook) to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this change. Happy to accept as an answer.